# Диалог выбора файла QFileDialog::getOpenFileName срабатывает дважды

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь вызвать диалог выбора файла в Qt, использую следующий вызов:

```
auto file_name = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Select file"), tr("/home/Downloads"));
```

Он почему-то порождает два одинаковых окна выбора файла, одно за другим, вместо одного. После того, как отработает второе окно, далее все работает как надо.

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: Может быть Вы два раза вызываете эту функцию ?

Comment: по одной строчке сложно что-то сказать, почитайте, [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Попробую пованговать, что путаница с сигналами-слотами.